# Unity not working after changes using compiz config

Tags: unity, compiz, 14.04

I have made some changes to effects using compiz config, however ever since doing this the launcher, taskbar, and borders around windows has disappeared.

I have tried reinstalling unity and compiz through terminal (via ALT-F1), but to no avail, any advice would be greatly appreciated.